# Remote login to ubuntu 14.04 over the internet using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access, putty, remote-server

I'm trying to setup my old laptop for remote access. I have installed ubuntu 14.04 in it and need to access it over the internet(not LAN) using ssh. I need to access only the terminal.

Following are the steps I have taken, but when I try to connect to it from a windows desktop using putty. I get the message "Connection timed out"

1, Installed ssh server in ubuntu
2, Since my ISP had a dynamic ip, I used with dynu.com for a host name is using it instead.
3, I have installed ddclient in my ubuntu although I'm not sure if I need it. I believe I have set it correctly.
4, My home computer is not at the getway (not wired), so I'm using port forwarding to forward port 22 to my local ip.

This is how I use putty in windows
hostname: xxxxx.dynu.com 
port    : 22
connection Type: ssh
click open.

Also, I tried to ping the hostname from a different network, it also gives me the same message.
I'm rather new to ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your dynamic hostname is registered OK?
Check this by going to www.whatismyip.com or something like that from the same network your Ubuntu server is located on to get your external IP, write it down.
Then do `nslookup xxx.dynu.com` and check if both IP adresses are the same.

Also make sure your Ubuntu server is assigned a static IP either through a static DHCP lease or configured manually. Then make sure your port forward is 100% correct to the static IP of the Ubuntu server.

Also good to remember is that it can take a few hours for changes in DNS records to take effect due to the TTL. Sometimes it helps to clear the local DNS cache on your Windows computer by doing `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Comment: Thanks patrick! I made a new account using duckdns.com and it is working perfectly now. Thanks again.